# Do trend detection algorithms use differential equation? If not then why? if they do what are some of them?

Tags: derivatives, statistical-inference, chi-squared

All the trend detection algorithms(for social networks) that I have seen use some kind of an average based on the previous data and for every new recording they check how far it is from the average. The problem I see with this approach is:

1. how can we remove noises from the past data?
2. We would need something that works on a sequence of data and not on a particular point, it is not about the peaks but whether a particular sequence of data will lead to a one.
3. Another problem with average based methods are lack of past data

Comment: There is the huge topic of observer design...maybe they count into your definition of trend detection algorithm? Noise is removed by having both a model for the system and for the noise. And all observers operate on streams of data

Comment: @NeitherNor could you direct me towards relevant material? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try wiki first: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_observer . But it's really a huge topic, with all kinds of how which type of noise is handled...

Comment: Ohh..thank you for that..but could you point at some literature that talks about their application to algorithms for trend detection

Comment: As I already stated, it depends how exactly you define trend detection. If your definition is broad enough, all observers are trend detection algorithms. Then, all I can do is to point at the whole field. I could only point at something specific if you tell me which type of trends you want to detect. Are we talking of Twitter, health monitoring, global warming, the stock exchange, electrical power stations,...?

Comment: yeah twitter or any social networking platform